# My html links are not showing up in safari

Tags: html, safari, href

I have this site and there are a lot of links in it. Only 4 links of the 5 are not showing up in the sharing object. This only apears in safari. My question is then why are this 4 links not showing up in my sharing object in the browser safari.

It is in the pc browser safari 8.0.3
In my safari 5 browser on windows the links show up

This is my site: http://www.tholexos.nl

Thnx for all your help!

EDIT: So I mean the links under the text --> Deel deze pagina op:

Comment: what? in what browser and pc? I have problems with safari 8.0.3 on mac yosmite

Comment: Yes it works on windows... But not on mac for me :-(